# name already defined in console!?

Tags: javascript

Could anyone explain why this code returns

> ""

in firebug console?

**Don't down-vote thinking it's just a typo!** :O
I was curious to know why **it doesn't throw an error**!!!

```
function mds() {
  var {
    namex,
    score,
    className
  }
  = {
    namex: 'NAME',
    score: '10',
    className: 'Oop'
  };
  this.test = function () {
    return name;
  };
}
var x = new mds();
x.test()
```

I would also love to hear more details on this type of variable mapping (or a link) ?

---

UPDATE:

I would like to know why **name** is predefined with value **""** in console?

Comment: Can we assign variables like that?

Comment: @Sourabh- In ES6 you can. [Destructuring assignment](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-destructuring-assignment.html)

Comment: Where's `name` coming from?

Comment: @Josh It is just a typo! but, didn't throw an error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript part of the explanation here is simple.

When you do this:

```
  this.test = function () {
    return name;
  };
```

It will first look for a variable named `name` in the scope of the function `this.test()`. When `name` is not found there, it will check in the parent function's scope as well. And since `name` is not defined there as well, it will look in the global scope, which is `window`, and returns the value of `window.name`, which in this case is an empty string. This (`window.name`) is what you are seeing when you run `name` in the console (or Firebug). This much is simple.

The value of `window.name` is decided according to it's definition in the HTML Standard (not according to ECMAScript rules). [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name) MDN page says:

> window.name - Gets/sets the name of the window.

And in your case, the name of the window is empty, hence the empty string you are getting. That's the simpler explanation of why `window.name` is empty.

If you really want to understand why `window.name` is empty here, you need to check out the [HTML Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#dom-name) for what it says about *browsing contexts*. It says that the value of `window.name` will be the name of the current *browsing context*.

> A *browsing context* is an environment in which Document objects are presented to the user. ([from the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#browsing-context))

For example, when you create a link in HTML using the below code, the `target` attribute specifies the target browsing context in which the page is to be opened.

```
<a href="page.html" target="TargetName">Click me</a>
```

See more examples in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cenuti/1/edit?html,js,output).

Hope this was somewhat helpful. Read the HTML Spec to understand more about [browsing contexts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#browsing-context).

Answer (score 1):

Even if you run the below code you get "".

```
function ha() {
return name;
}
ha();
```

returning of "" has no way related to

```
var {
    namex,
    score,
    className
  }
  = {
    namex: 'NAME',
    score: '10',
    className: 'Oop'
  };
```

Another way to test it is, Just type 'name' press enter in console.

> ""

Updating as per "Krishna" observation.

Looks like name is predefined in console context. So if the user doesnt have another declaration of name within the scope the console returns an empty string "". If user has declared name="xyz" then xyz is returned

Comment: Is the **name** predefined? I got it mixed with assignment

Comment: nope. its not predefined. like i said i think you get "" when the variable is not defined

Comment: I got a **ReferenceError: a is not defined**

Comment: But, when I try **name** it returns **""**

Comment: true it must be referenced in console context, unless we explicity declare it again we get the value of this predefined 'name'

Answer (score 1):

**name** is a legitimate ***window*** property.
Windows can have names. And they can be useful.

As in:

```
<a href="named.htm" target="namedWindow">Open a new window, with the name of namedWindow!</a>
```

...and to make this more informal, we should add that: a link with a named target will either open in an existing *window* with that *name* or will create a new one with the given name in case it's not.

And because the "name" token is a global property of the window context; stating: *name* in the console or anywhere in the script will of course return an empty value (of a proper/accepted *type*), that is: a *string*. In this case [meaning the window.name hasn't been defined yet] an empty ("") string, is the only correct value for that property.

Whereas an unset event of a window, or any DOM element - if it exists - should return *null*, not *undefined* or god forbid an empty string, because they (event properties) expect functions; and functions are of type object, and null represents an empty object.

However, an unset, inline event attribute of an html element - should return an empty string ("").

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
var {
  namex: name,
  score: score,
  className
} = {
  namex: 'NAME',
  score: '10',
  className: 'Oop'
};
```

actually object have to be key value pair